# Convert m4a to mp3 using Sound Converter

Tags: mp3, m4a, soundconverter

I'm trying to convert some m4a sounds to mp3 using Sound Convert but I get the following error:

> Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: Apple Lossless Audio (ALAC) decoder

I have also installed the following plugin:

> gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly

Comment: `ffmpeg -i my.m4a -acodec mp3 -ac 2 -ab 192k my.mp3` ?

Comment: ...or `avconv -i input.m4a ouptut.mp3`. If not yet istalled -> (apt-get install libav-tools)